# How to add a row to the beginning of a table with react

Tags: reactjs

A have created a table and a form that add a row to this table, it is working fine, but instead of adding the line to the bottom i would like to add as the first row.

What would be the best solution for that? I can add more code if needed.

this is the code in the component at the table file:

```js
//code
constructor(props) {
   this.state = {

        categories: [],

    }
    this.addCategory = this.addCategory.bind(this);
  }

// code

 addCategory(id, slug, title) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      categories: [...prevState.categories, {id, slug, title }]
    }));
  }

<CategoryForm 
  addCategory={this.addCategory}  />
```

this is the Form file:

```js
 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const form = event.target;
    const id = ""
    const title = form.elements["title"].value;
    const slug = form.elements["slug"].value;
    this.props.addCategory( id, slug, title);
    form.reset();
      
  }

// code

render() {

  <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

       <Button>Submit</Button>
   </Form>
}
```

Comment: Was that simple! Thanks, if you want to post your answer, i can mark as solution! @pilchard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply append the new row to the beginning of the state array instead of the end.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
      categories: [{id, slug, title }, ...prevState.categories]
    }));
```